# Mantel's test with non-symmetrical data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I am struggling with a Mantel's test and I could use some advice.

I have worked with ade4 and vegan packages in R but I have had to trim down my data so that it is symmetrical and change it to a distance matrix.

Is there a way to run mantel's in R without having to convert my matrices to distance matrices?

Example:

Matrix 1 - 
[image: Matrix 1]

[image: Matrix 2]